# Insert N rows with date interval

Tags: mysql, date, insert

I need to insert rows into a database, where every row is the same except a date column which should have its date incremented by 1 week for each new row. So, basically this:

```
  for(n = 0; n<X; n++)
      insert into events (date, title) values (start_date + 7*n, 'static title');
```

Any MySQL trick that can be used to do this?

Comment: How is start_date determined?

Comment: It's given by me, for example `2014-01-22`. The goal is to end up with one row for every Wednesday, X weeks into the future.

Comment: insert into events (date, title) values (DATE_ADD(start_date,  INTERVAL n WEEK), 'static title');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT
 'static_title' AS title,
 DATE_ADD(@start_date, INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 WEEK) AS result_date
FROM
 (SELECT
 (two_1.id + two_2.id + two_4.id + 
 two_8.id + two_16.id) AS id
 FROM
 (SELECT 0 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS id) AS two_1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 2 id) AS two_2
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 4 id) AS two_4
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 8 id) AS two_8
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 id UNION ALL SELECT 16 id) AS two_16
 ) AS sequence
 CROSS JOIN
-- @i:=0 for not including current week
 (SELECT @i:=-1, @start_date:=CURDATE()) AS init
WHERE
  sequence.id<10;
```

-that will produce N rows (here `N=10`). To insert rows, just use `INSERT .. SELECT` syntax. Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3501a7/7). Also in sample `start_date` is set to `CURDATE()` - but you can easily adjust that in query, of course.

Comment: Wow, what does that even do? I'm not sure I understand any of it :p

Comment: It will do the work for you :p Actually, since there are no sequences in MySQL - needed values are generates as sum of powers of `2` (like `3 = 2^1 + 2^0`) - and needed count of rows is derived from `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: Is there any connection between number of cross joins with powers of 2, and the sequence id? If I wanted N=500 for example, would you need more?

Comment: Well, sequence _is generated_ as a sum of powers of 2 (you can execute query separately to check that). Sequence id will be consecutive integer, but to limit it with some value, where is `WHERE` clause. I.e. `sequence.id<10` will limit that to only 1-st ten values, so `1..10`. In fact, that is needed only for generating rows. In your particular case you can get rid of `@i` (because you need consecutive week addition) - so query above can be simplified